# Sharepoint 2007 publishing page review alerts vs SharePoint 2010

Tags: migration, document, publishing

In SP 2007 we could when creating a a new publishing page configure a review date that would alert the page contact when the page needs to be reviewed. Can we do the same thing in SharePoint 2010 on a document library item?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use expiration policies (retention) for this?

Policies in SP2010 are the same as in SP2007.